# How to install ceiling light fixtures at the intersection of a beam and a wall

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, light-fixture, ceiling

I recently moved into an apartment in Austria, where you're responsible for installing all light fixtures yourself (tenant/landlord laws are very interesting here). Most of the wiring is straightforward, centered in the middle of the room with no excess cables. However, two (A & B) are positioned in tight corners against a wooden beam, and some have protruding plastic pipe encasing them. The last one (C) has an excess length of cable that inspires fear.

My question is, how do we install fixtures here?
For A & B, do fixtures even exist that can be positioned flush against a corner? Are we meant to cut open the ceiling and re-route the wiring into a different position?
For C, my husband suggests we either shove the majority of the cable back up into the ceiling, or cut off the excess and reattach the junction boxes. These after I naysayed his idea to keep the excess hanging out of the wall like the world's ugliest pendant light.

All ideas appreciated!!

A - upstairs hallway

[image: Upstairs hallway wiring]

B - bedroom

[image: Upstairs bedroom wiring]

C - living room

[image: Living room wiring]

Comment: That does not look safe at all.

Comment: @Huesmann it seems that in Europe, the requirement to have every wire junction inside a box doesn't exist like it does in the US. It might have something to do with the fact that they seem to use screw-terminal blocks for all wiring instead of wire nuts like we do.

Comment: C might be to have multiple lights as one reason for extra wire.  With just that one small light, you might not see the lego block to miss stepping on it.

Answer (score 0):

For the first two (hallway & bedroom) it looks like you can install any sort of fixture you'd like.

- It's hard to tell from the perspective in the pictures, but mount an up-light on *top* of the beams for a non-direct light reflecting off the ceiling.
- Mount a sconce on the side of the beam that can direct light out/down.
- Mount a "ceiling" type fixture on the bottom of the beam.

For the third picture, well, yeah, that's a *lot* of extra wire! Double check with the landlord about that one - maybe there's a reason for it. If not, cut it off so there is ~12" (300mm) of cable, mount your ceiling fixture of choice, and push the extra wire up into the ceiling.